# Error in readxl::read_excel: is_null(n) : object 'rlang_is_null' not found

Tags: r, rlang, readxl

When trying to run the sample code given [here](http://readxl.tidyverse.org/):

```
xlsx_example <- readxl_example("datasets.xlsx")
read_excel(xlsx_example)
```

I get the error `Error in is_null(n) : object 'rlang_is_null' not found`

Info about my R session:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] readxl_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.13     lattice_0.20-35  ape_5.0          tidyr_0.7.2      cellranger_1.1.0 grid_3.4.2       plyr_1.8.4      
 [8] jsonlite_1.5     nlme_3.1-131     gtable_0.2.0     magrittr_1.5     scales_0.5.0     ggplot2_2.2.1    rlang_0.1.2.9000
[15] lazyeval_0.2.1   ggtree_1.10.0    rvcheck_0.0.9    treeio_1.2.0     tools_3.4.2      glue_1.2.0       purrr_0.2.4     
[22] munsell_0.4.3    yaml_2.1.14      parallel_3.4.2   compiler_3.4.2   colorspace_1.3-2 tibble_1.3.4
```

I presume the error points to [`rlang` package](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang) though.

I also tried to install older versions of `readxl` package, but I got the same error.

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/readxl/readxl_0.1.1.tar.gz", 
                 repos=NULL, type="source")
# or
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/readxl/readxl_0.1.0.tar.gz", 
                 repos=NULL, type="source")
```

Comment: `rlang_is_null` is a [compiled function in `rlang`](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/blob/2f7836b528a1166b20331a0637be7f3446e23f83/src/rlang/sexp.c#L80), so perhaps things are not being loaded correctly. I suggest you manually remove the `rlang` installation directory (I tend to "move out of the way" vice delete) then reinstall it to make sure it is compiled correctly, then restart R and try again.

Comment: Thanks a lot @r2evans ! Your suggestion worked. You may consider adding your comment as answer since it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rlang_is_null` is a [compiled function](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/blob/2f7836b528a1166b20331a0637be7f3446e23f83/src/rlang/sexp.c#L80) within [`rlang`](https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang). If "restarting R" (the analogy of the windows 3-finger salute) doesn't resolve things, it sounds like the package installation is bad.

Try:

1. moving it out of the way (eventually for deletion, but I don't like deleting if other aspects still work);
2. re-install `rlang`, likely the binary of it (default);
3. if that doesn't work, consider compiling the source (assuming Rtools is installed ... have not tried but should work fine); then
4. Restart R. I usually don't trust `detach` or `unload` and a subsequent `library` to fix problems with packages with compiled objects (mostly under windows), so a clean restart is my suggestion.